# Armadillo - initialize a matrix and fill matrix with values

Tags: armadillo

I would like to fill a matrix column wise. I have the following numpy code which I am having difficulty converting to C++ Armadillo.

```py
# numpy code
m = np.zeros((nrows, nrows))
# fill a matrix of lags
for i in range(0, nrows):
    r = np.roll(vec_v, i)
    m[:, i] = r
```

where `vec_v` is a single column vector and `nrows` is the number of rows in that column vector.

This is my Armadillo attempt

```cpp
# armadillo conversion
mat m(nrows, nrows); m.zeroes();

for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
  vec r = shift(vec_v, i)
  m.col(i).fill(r);
}
```

What is the reccommended way to initialize a matrix then fill the values column-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` operator should work here.

```
mat m(nrows, nrows); m.zeros();

for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
  vec r = shift(vec_v, i);
  m.col(i) = r;
}
```

Matrix initialization can be simplified and the generation of the temporary `r` vector can be avoided, as below.

```
mat m(nrows, nrows, fill::zeros);

for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
  m.col(i) = shift(vec_v, i);
}
```